# How to reference a form and change properties (height and width) from a function in Qt

Tags: c++, forms, qt, qt-creator, qt5

I'm starting with Qt trying to migrate from VB6. And now I'm trying to change the size of a window (UI form) from a function, so before doing that in the action that opens the form I do this:

```
void F::on_actionCte_triggered()
{
    Frm_ABM_Ctes *W = new Frm_ABM_Ctes(uF->mdiArea);
    W->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    W->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
    W->showNormal();
    int Hi = (this->height()/3) - (W->height()/3);
    int Wi = (this->width()/3) - (W->width()/3);
    W->setGeometry(Wi,Hi,W->width(),W->height());
}
```

That works fine, the idea is that if I gonna do a lot of forms I want to call a function where it changes the geometry property of the child form. Like: Function(Parent,child) and then use Parent and Child as dynamic objects in my function (as I do in visual basic or VS)

So I did this:

```
void F::on_actionCte_triggered()
{
    Frm_ABM_Ctes *W = new Frm_ABM_Ctes(uF->mdiArea);
    W->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    W->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
    W->showNormal();
    FormS(This,W)
}
```

Where `FormS` is in a `*.h` file (which of course I include) and goes like this:

```
void FormS(QMainWindow Par, QMdiSubWindow Chi)
{
    int Hi = (Par.height()/3) - (Chi.height()/3);
    int Wi = (Par.width()/3) - (Chi.width()/3);
    Chi.setGeometry(Wi,Hi,Chi.width(),Chi.height());
}
```

and it gives

```
error: could not convert 'this' from 'F* const' to 'QMainWindow'
     FormS(this,W);
                   ^
```

I don't know which is the best way to approach to my problem. Is there a way to create a public pointer and change any property of that form, or something like that?

Thanks for taking the time to read my problem any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are trying to pass pointers into this method, so you'll need to adjust the method to take those pointers. Secondly, I'm not sure what F is (you haven't shown the declaration), but if it's a QMainWindow subclass this will work fine like so:

```
void FormS(QMainWindow *Par, QMdiSubWindow *Chi)
{
    int Hi = (Par->height()/3) - (Chi->height()/3);
    int Wi = (Par->width()/3) - (Chi->width()/3);
    Chi->setGeometry(Wi, Hi, Chi->width(), Chi->height());
}
```